# Jmeter: I can send request only 10k during some time

Tags: jmeter, load, stress-testing

I ran into a problem that I can only send 10k requests. I have the following conditions.

- Request: 4
- Number of threads: 4200
- Ramp-up period: 300 sec

During 300 sec(5 min) I have to have ~16800 namely (4*14)*300=16800 but Jmeter stuck on 10k and test is never end.

Please help me with resolving this. My request is the following. I need to load the system where we have 4 request that each request should send 14 times per 1 second.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
2. If your test is "stuck" again there could be 2 reasons for this:

   - JMeter cannot handle that many threads due to your machine hardware or software limitations. In this case you will need to get another load generator machine and switch to [Distributed Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/distributed-testing-in-jmeter).
   - The system under test cannot handle that many requests. By default JMeter will wait for the response forever and if the response doesn't come the request will never end. If this is the case consider setting reasonable connect and response timeouts. For [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers it can be done under "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request Defaults](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults)

     [image]

The reason of JMeter getting "stuck" can be determined by [taking and analyzing JMeter's thread dump](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-dump)